# Where is Bootstrap's dashboard.css stylesheet?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is probably a silly question on StackExchange. Please forgive me for asking but where I am trying to follow the example to create a Dashboard theme as shown in the Custom Component example guide of Twitter Bootstrap. So I've downloaded the source code of the bootstrap distribution zip. But there is no file name dashboard.css anywhere. I googled it but it seemed to take me to a third party web site wrapbootstrap.com(Is this where to get it? ) If not, Where is it? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find it on the github repo:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/examples/dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You can see the styling of the different themes here: https://bootswatch.com